# How to validate the existence of a JSON file before load it with the XMLHttpRequest Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am working loading a JSON file from a relative local path into my web based app. To do this I am using an XMLHttpRequest object, as following:

```
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'myFyle.json', true);
xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
    }
}
xobj.send(null);
```

My issue is that I can't manage the browser error (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) when `myFyle.json` is not found. I would like to load an standard `.json` file (e.g. `myStandardFile.json`) when this happens.

Does anybody has an idea to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Pedro.

Comment: That is what the status code will tell you. So if you get the error, you need to make another call.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking in the response a solution for that... but the `xobj.status` when the local file is not located is 0.

Comment: file protocol returns "0", that is what happens when you are not using a webserver, but loading via file://c:....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xobj.status === 404` to detect 'file not found'.

> The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found"
>   web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link;

In case of 404 you can load your default file like this:

```
function load(file, callback) {    
    var defaultFile = "myStandardFile.json";
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', file, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState !== 4) return true;
        if (xobj.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
          //File not found.
         //The second condition just to prevent endless calls
         //in case if your default file doesn't exist
        } else if (xobj.status === 404 && file !== defaultFile) {
            load(defaultFile, callback);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
}

load("myFyle.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Demo:

```js
function load(file, callback) {
 var defaultFile = "https://httpbin.org/user-agent";
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', file, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState !== 4) return true;
        if (xobj.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
            //File not found
        } else if (xobj.status === 404 && file !== defaultFile) {
            load(defaultFile, callback);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
}

load("https://httpbin.org/inexistentFile.json", function(data) {
 console.log(data);
})
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, your answer helps me a lot... Thank you! But just one thing, when the file loading fails, the `xobj.status` is not 404. It's 0.